# DialogFlow: 'Add Response' not working in Web Demo

Tags: dialogflow-es

As you can see from the image below, putting two separate 'text response' buttons gives me a two line response.

However, I only get either one of the responses (at random) when I use the Web Demo integration. Either 'Hi, welcome!' or 'How may I help?'

Anyone got any ideas why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where my image link went... anyway read a few Google forums that said this isn't possible. Solved the problem by just pressing space until it went onto a new line.

Answer (score -1):

When you are in Default responses tab, then it gives two options: Text response, custom payload
You should select Google assistant tab before clicking the add response button. Thus You can see all options about responses.

Comment: The Google Assistant tab is only for Google Assistant specific messages. The OP mentioned that they are using the Web Demo, so Google Assistant responses are not supported.